# What is context param in web.xml?

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

What is `<context-param>` in `web.xml`? Why do we use it?

For instance, what does the following do?

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: If your question is specifically about the contextConfigLocation parameter used in Spring, then this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650695/some-information-about-spring-web-xml-context-param-and-listener-tag-refere .  Does the answer to that question help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a spring web application, `contextConfigLocation` context param gives the location of the root context.

Your config is *strange*, for a spring-mvc application, because by default, `servletname-servlet.xml` (where `servletname` is the name of a `DispatcherServlet` servlet) is the child application context for the servlet.

What is current (and recommended by Spring documentation) is to have a root context that will contain the model layer (service, persistence and business beans) and a servlet context that will contain the controller and view layer (controller, view resolvers, interceptors). The rule is that bean in servlet context can use beans of root context but the reciprocal is false.

Comment: Thanks, Deep words in few Lines.

Answer (score 3):

Some time you will be in a situation where you want to set some parameter and want to access it through out your whole web application.Then is the time when context parameters specified in the `web.xml` come into play.It comes with an advantage(*along with its availability through out the web-app*) that you just needs to do change in the `web.xml` file only,whenever you want to change that particular value.You specify the `context-param` like

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mypackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
            <param-name>email</param-name>
            <param-value>myemail@email.com</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

and can access it like

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println(getServletContext().getInitParameter("email"));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

like a key value pair

they can be used to read some value anywhere in the web app

See
http://www.factorypattern.com/storing-parameters-in-webxml-context-param-init-param/