# How can I get the filesystem path of the JSP from a servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, web

It's proving to be a tedious issue for me. I'm trying to make a dynamic web page which requires me to populate a dropdown menu with items that are dynamically generated from an executable on the server. The executable is local relative to the JSP in the filesystem.

I know that it can be done because I can run an executable with:

```
<form action="./my_executable">
```

But if I try doing this from a JSP Servlet (something I'm required to do), the:

```
<%= new File("./my_executable").getPath() %>
```

Gives me a different path in the filesystem entirely.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the path to the executable in a web application context parameter instead of depending on some relative position from the JSP?

Comment: Please elaborate. Also I'd like to add that there's four or five clones of the website/program on different processors, each with a unique data set that's dynamically generated.
I can't simply install the executable at some hardcoded filesystem path - it must be relative directory. The JSP is installed /somewhere/in/filesystem/base/file.jsp in one machine and /some/other/filesystem/base/file.jsp in another.

Comment: In your web.xml, you can put context parameters (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174170/what-is-context-param-in-web-xml) and access them from your JSP page, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039220/how-can-i-get-context-parameter-value-in-jsp

Comment: There is no web.xml for me to use - the JSP page is standalone.

Comment: When you use something like <%= new File("").getAbsolutePath() %> it will give the path to the folder where the Java process was started. If you want the path to your web app you should use something like <%= application.getRealPath("/") %>